# Where is the SharePoint 2013 Search User Guide?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I can't find a Search User's Guide!  I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, on-premise.

Comment: That's a broad topic..anything in particular you are looking for? Here's a start: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14382.sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-and-enterprise-search-survival-guide.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  I also need to enter at least 30 characters to be able to submit this as an answer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163973.aspx